# Communication between components (software design question)

Tags: model-view-controller, software-design

I have an application with the following UI components:

- Main Menu
- Folders Tree
- Query Builder
- Tabbed Lists (each tab has a grid that can display data entities)

The application is based on MVC, so each component listed above has a controller and a view.

The first three components need to display data entities on the list (as new tabs):

- Double clicking on a folder will display the folder's items in a new list.
- When clicking the search button in the query builder it will open the search results in a new tab.
- When clicking "Open..." menu item it and selecting a file it will open a new tab with the items in the file.

Since there could be a lot of items the process of loading them from the database is done asynchronously by the grid (the grid is being filled as you are looking at it).

My question is this: which of the following is a "cleaner" design? (if you have better solutions, I will appreciate it very much)

The first solution I have is to use an [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707867.aspx), define a "ShowQuery" event, make the lists controller subscribe to it, and the other controllers will publish it when they want to display the query results.

The other solution is something like the Unity Container, and from the other controllers resolve the "IListsController" interface, and call the "ShowQuery" method.

Comment: This is a question about the Microsoft MVC .NET framework, rather than a general software design question relating to the MVC pattern.

Comment: If you're referring to Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, then it has nothing to do with that.

If you're referring to the Composite Application Guidance, then also no, I'm using my own implementation of an MVC framework, suited for my needs. I'm using concepts and ideas from the CAG framework.

Also, this question is only for .NET, I have a similar framework in javascript and python.

Comment: Oops, I ment to say "this question ISN'T only for .NET"